# How to build and deploy Angular to multiple environments?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using Azure DevOps / Pipelines, I'm able to build and deploy a Angular application to a specific environment.

The way that works today it's something like, 1 Angular (same code) it's built in 2 different environments. To that I have 2 pipelines with the same tasks except for the last one that is a different slot. In resume it's this

```
Pipeline Staging

1. Node.js tool installer
2. npm (install -g @angular/cli)
3. npm (npm install)
4. npm (run build)
5. Azure App Service deploy (slot: Dev)

Pipeline Prod

1. Node.js tool installer
2. npm (install -g @angular/cli)
3. npm (npm install)
4. npm (run build)
5. Azure App Service deploy (slot: Production)
```

Now I want to improve this, using DevOps / Releases, but I can't figure it out how to configure.

This is what I'm trying to do

[image]

```
1. Setup
1.1. Node.js tool installer
1.2. npm (install -g @angular/cli)
1.3. npm (npm install)

2. Build
2.1. npm (run build)

3. Deploy
3.1. Azure App Service deploy (slot: Dev)

4. Deploy
4.1. Azure App Service deploy (slot: Production)
```

But I always get some error like the path not found

```
##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\s\Artifact (build)\dist

##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\s\Artifact Dashboard (build)

##[warning]Directory 'D:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'Artifact Dashboard (build)'.

##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\Artifact (build)
```

It seems something too simple to be so hard to configure. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing first two steps (Setup and Build) in Pipelines and then Deployment in Releases. In Pipelines you will create artifact which is code you want to be published, pipelines must be ending with publish build artifact task, it will create that folder. You will then deploy it in releases.

Pipeline Should be ending with publish build artifact:
[publish build artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFzs1.png)

You are then using this artifact in release.

Comment: Right! In pipelines create artifact would be... "Publish build artifacts"? I guess that I'm missing how to link the artifact from pipeline to release deploy stage

Comment: Yes, edited message. You can map artifact in Releases -> Artifacts

Answer (score 0):

At pipeline I had to add Copy Files to

```
Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    Contents: 'dist/**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

and also fix this

```
Publish Artifact: Artifact Dashboard (build)

steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: Artifact Dashboard (build)'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Parameters.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'Artifact Dashboard (build)'
```

At release stage I had to

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy Name'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ***
    WebAppName: Name
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: GroupName
    SlotName: dev
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Artifact Dashboard (build staging)/Artifact Dashboard (build)/dist'
```